# Can my Android device replace a heart monitor watch?

Tags: fitness

Can my Android device replace a heart monitor watch? Maybe there are good apps out there for monitoring heart rates?

Many people use special watches, so I wonder if their phone can do it already instead.

Answer (score 7):

I use an app called [Instant Heart Rate](http://www.appbrain.com/app/instant-heart-rate/si.modula.android.instantheartrate) which uses the phone's camera to measure your pulse.

Comment: +1 It's a neat app. I offered some tech info on it in this answer http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/best-scientific-apps-for-android/2753#2753. (Not affiliated with the app, just think it's a great idea).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried any of these but [Android Heart Monitor](http://androidheartmonitor.com/) sounds like it could be the sort of thing you're after?

Then there's also [Endomondo Sports Tracker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/endomondo-sports-tracker/com.endomondo.android) which is apparently compatible with the [Polar Wearlink](http://www.polar.fi/en/products/accessories/WearLink_transmitter) heart rate monitor (more at [Endomondo.com](http://www.endomondo.com/)).

And also [Sports Track Live](http://www.sportstracklive.com/help/android) which is apparently compatible with Zephyr Hxm, BioHarness and Polar Wearlink.

Obviously with all of these even if the software's free you still need to buy the heart rate monitor itself.

Answer (score 2):

[What's My Heart Rate](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vitrox.facion.gui)

This app is slightly different from the rest in the market. **It does not require you to pressed on camera lens. Hence, you will not dirty your camera lens.**

The product description is as follow.

> Measure your heart rate by just looking at your screen. Easy and
>   convenient without needed to finger press on your camera lens.
>
> Your heartbeat causes micro color changes on your face. Our software
>   uses front camera and advanced software algorithm to detect these
>   micro changes, with beat-to-beat accuracy. The algorithm is built
>   based on realiable non-contact photoplethysmography concept
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoplethysmograph).
>
> This breakthrough technology allows you to measure your heart rate in
>   an easy and unobtrusive way.

It is using computer vision technology. Hence, its result is more sensitive to environment lighting, and face motion. I cannot comment much on its accuracy, as no further detailed data being published. But I can see there is different in my heartbeat reading, before and after sports.

Here is one of the screenshot pick from the product site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are options that may let you use a standard ANT+ heart rate belt so you can easaly get continuas recording while exercising.  You either need a phone with built in ANT support which is mainly some of the Sony Xperias but not all.  Or with a modern phone you can use a Usb Ant stick I have some [details about this](http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=usb-ant-stick) on my website.